# Work done by external agent in moving an object from point A to point B and then again to A comes out be positive

Tags: energy, work

Consider the following situation :
[image]

Calculating Work done in moving this object from position A to B :
\begin{align}  W = F.S = (10î).(5î) = 50 J\end{align}
Calculating Work done in moving this object from position B to A :
\begin{align}  W = F.S = (-10î).(-5î) = 50 J\end{align}
Adding this results in **100 J** but Work done should be zero since displacement is **zero**.

Can anyone please help me out in this ?

Answer (score 1):

Where you are going wrong is that the force does not change direction.

[image: Pushing block]

Suppose you are pushing the block by applying a force $F$ to it, and by the third law the block applies a force $-F$ to you. It doesn't matter whether you are pushing the block to the right, or whether the block is pushing you to the left. In both cases you are pushing rightwards with a force $+F$.

So if you push the block a distance $\ell$ to the right then the work you do is:

$$ W_1 = +F \times +\ell = +F\ell $$

If the block is pushing you to the left a distance $-\ell$ then you are still pushing rightwards so the work you do is now:

$$ W_2 = +F \times -\ell = -F\ell$$

And when we add $W_1$ and $W_2$ we get zero as expected. Where you went wrong is in the first step you calculated the work you do on the block, but in the second step you calculated the work the block does on you. That is, in the first step you used the force you apply to the block, but in the second step you used the force the block applies on you.

Comment: I am considering that first I pushed the block towards right and stopped there and then started pushing the block towards left.

Comment: But then you have pushed the block for 10 metres. In effect you are applying a non-conservative force to the block that is for any position $x$ the force has one direction during the first stage but a different direction in the second stage. Or looking at it another way if you write the force you apply as a function of position $F(x)$ then $F(x)$ is not a single valued function.

Comment: So in this case total work done is 100 Joule if consider the case given in question?

Comment: @ShekharDangi yes, if you push the block 5m then turn round and push in the opposite direction for 5m the work you do will be 100J. Assuming that the force required is due to friction with the floor, that 100J will have been converted to heat by the friction.

Answer (score 0):

System - block alone

**Interpretation 1**
The external force reverses direction.

[image]

Work done on block by external force in moving from $A$ to $B = +10\hat i \cdot +5\hat i = +50 \,\rm J$
Change in kinetic energy of block $= +50 \rm \, J$ as the speed of the block increases from zero.

Work done on block by external force in moving from $B$ to $A = -10\hat i \cdot -5\hat i = +50 \,\rm J$
$\rm \color{red}{Change}$ in kinetic energy of block $= +50 \rm \, J$

Total work done on the block by external force $= +50+50=+100\,\rm J \color{red} \ne $ change in kinetic energy of block.

So what is happening here?

From $A$ to $B$ the speed and hence the kinetic energy of the block is increasing due to the work done by the external force.

From $B$ to $A$ the speed and hence the kinetic energy of the block is decreasing due to the work done by the external force.

So although the external force does a total of $100\,\rm J$ of work, half of that was used to speed up the block ie there was a positive change of $50\,\rm J$  in kinetic energy, and the other half was used to slow down the block ie there was a negative change of $50\,\rm J$ in the kinetic energy, ie a total change in kinetic energy of $+50+(-50) = 0\rm\, J$.

**Interpretation 2**
The external force does not change direction.

[image]

Work done on block by external force in moving from $A$ to $B = +10\hat i \cdot +5\hat i = +50 \,\rm J$
Change in kinetic energy of block $= +50 \rm \, J$ as the speed of the block increases from zero.

What about the work done on block by external force in moving from $B$ to $A$?
Moving from $B$ to $A$ cannot happen unless there was another external force  acting on the block in the $-\hat i$ direction and with a magnitude greater that $10\rm\, N$.

Comment: Why is speed decreasing in second case?

Comment: @ShekharDangi in the second interpretation the speed increases when moving from $A$ to $B$ but for the black to get back to $A$ it must reverse its direction of motion.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thanks for it.